# How to make MVC 4 Razor Html.Raw work for assignment in HTML within script tags

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, jqote

For a project I'm using jqote for templating in JavaScript and HTML generated by MVC 4 with Razor.

Please have a look at the following code in HTML and Razor:

```
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/html">
    <p>Some html</p>
    @{string id = "<%=this.Id%>";}

    <!-- 1 -->
    @if(true) 
    {   
        @Html.Raw(@"<select id="""+id+@"""></select>")
    }
    <!-- 2 -->
    @if(true)
    {
        <select id="@Html.Raw(id)"></select>
    }
    <!-- 3 -->
    @Html.Raw(@"<select id="""+id+@"""></select>")
    <!-- 4 -->
    <select id="@Html.Raw(id)"></select>
    <!-- 5 -->
    <select id="<%=this.Id%>"></select>
</script>
```

The output is this:

```
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/html">
    <!-- 1 -->
    <select id="<%=this.Id%>"></select> <!--Good!-->
    <!-- 2 -->
    <select id="&lt;%=this.Id%&gt;"></select> <!--BAD!-->
    <!-- 3 -->
    <select id="<%=this.Id%>"></select> <!--Good!-->
    <!-- 4 -->
    <select id="<%=this.Id%>"></select> <!--Good!-->
    <!-- 5 -->
    <select id="<%=this.Id%>"></select> <!--Good!-->
</script>
```

Now, the problem is with the second select under `<!-- 2 -->`. One would expect the `Html.Raw` to kick in here but somehow it doesn't. Or Razor wants to HtmlEncode what's in there.

The question is: ***Does anyone have an idea why? Is this a bug or by design?***

Without the script tags it works. But we need the script tags cause we need to template in JavaScript.

Hardcoded it works, but we need to use a variable because this will not always be a template.

Without the `@if` it works, but it's there, we need it.

### Workarounds

These lines give similar good outputs:

```
@if(true)
{
    <select id= "@Html.Raw(id)"></select>
}
@if(true)
{
    <select id ="@Html.Raw(id)"></select>
}
@if(true)
{
    <select id @Html.Raw("=")"@Html.Raw(id)"></select>
}
```

We're planning to do this:

```
<script id="testTemplate" type="text/html">
    @{string id = @"id=""<%=this.Id%>""";}
    @if(true)
    {   
        <select @Html.Raw(id)></select>
    }
</script>
```

...to keep as to markup intact as much as possible.

Comment: Why aren't you using @Html.DropDownList(id)?

Comment: I'm having the same problem but with <img src="@Html.Raw(path)" />

It's transforming & into &amp;

Comment: There is a ticket and fix on github for that: https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/issues/181

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** After reading the code provided properly:

This looks like a bug. It is somehow connected to the id-attribute. Change the attribute to something else and it works.

```
@if(true) 
{   
    <select data-id="@Html.Raw(id)"></select>
}
```

Obviously this is not a solution, only a verification. Your example 4 more or less implies that it's not by design, otherwise that one should fail aswell.

Comment: Thanks, but this is the same as #1 with additional `<text>` tags. #4 is without the `if`. The `if` needs to be there...

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, I've tested a bit and updated my "answer".. Unless somebody else can provide a better explanation I would say you have found a bug.